# What is best way to pentest an AngularJS web app with a REST backend?

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, javascript, angularjs

Traditionall webapps are often pentested by vulnerability scanners like Burp Suite, OWASP ZAP or with the other gazillion tools included in Kali. 
But what is the best way to pentest automatically a JavaScript web-app (AngularJS) with a REST backend? And what are the recommended tools for that task?

Comment: Is the question specifically about *automated* testing/scanning or are you asking about ways to pentest Angular apps in general?

Comment: Please note that fully automated webapp pentests only find some very-low hanging fruits. Any serious pentest goes way further than that.

Answer (score 3):

For Angular.JS, there is a very handy tool Batarang Chrome Extension in the Chrome Extension Store:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk

For testing REST you can still use Burp, Fiddler or ZAP.

Here is a link to REST OWASP cheat sheet:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet